# Choose default for VS Code's context menu option "Open in integrated terminal"

Tags: visual-studio-code

**The problem...**

How do I choose which terminal VS Code will open from the right click context menu "Open in integrated terminal".

I have successfully configured VS Code to open WSL as my default new terminal.

However, when I use the context menu option from the folder structure "Open in integrated terminal", it does not open WSL but opens GitBash.

My objective is to right click on a folder, and have a WSL terminal open at that position in the file system.

Which option do I need to change in VS Code to adjust which terminal opens for this context menu option?

**What I've tried...**

Changing the default terminal in VS Code.

Searching for the solution with various search engines.

Comment: It would be great to have the option to select a terminal configuration...